# How to use differential to interpret a countinuous funtion $z(x,y)=\int \frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x}dx+\phi(y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

**Question:**
Let $z=z(x,y)$ is continuous, and I wonder why the following statement holds?
$$z(x,y)=\int \frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x}dx+\phi(y)=\int \frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial y}dy+\varphi(x).$$

1. How to interpret by differntial, $dz=z^\prime_xdx+z^\prime_ydy$, to explain why we need two partial derivatives to compute differential, but only one to intergrate?
2. Which computation of differential does not hold, so that the formular I 'invent', $\int dz=\int z^\prime_xdx+z^\prime_ydy$ fail?
3. Is there any connections between this question and *Line integral of a vector field* and *Green's theorem*? (See my discussion nearly in the last part of this question.)
4. What about non-continuous funtion? Is there anything similiar to antiderivative in two variables?

**What confused me:**
Why after intergrating both sides, (even though I cannot interpret the below notation, maybe something similiar to line integral), $$z=\int dz\ne\int z^\prime_xdx+z^\prime_ydy,$$

and $$z=\int dz\ne\int z^\prime_xdx+\int z^\prime_ydy,$$

where I guess the last one should be right if $z^\prime_x$ does not contain $y$ and $z^\prime_y$ does not contain $x$, since $$z=\int dz=\int z^\prime_xdx+\int z^\prime_ydy=\int P(x)dx + Q(y)dy=\int d(\int P(x) dx + \int Q(y)dy).$$

**What I am thinking:**
I think this problem should be answered from the very beginning, the differentiation and integration in one variable. For $y=f(x)$, holds $\frac{dy}{dx}=f^\prime(x)$, and thus,

$$f(x)=\int dy=\int \frac{dy}{dx} dx=\int f^\prime(x)dx.$$

To reduce misunderstanding, consider frome the definition of integral. Let $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$, known that $\Delta y=f^\prime(x)\Delta x+o(\Delta x)$, then

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f^\prime ({x_i}) \Delta x=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f^\prime ({x_i}) \frac{\Delta y-o(x)}{f^\prime(x_i)}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \Delta y-o(x)=y(b)-y(a).$$

Now for two variables, it is obvious to infer, $$z=\int dz=\int z^\prime_x dx+z^\prime_y dy$$

Here comes the 2nd question: which computation of differential does not hold, so that the formular above fail?

However, even myself cannot point out the meaning inside. Let $z=z(x,y)$, $\rho=\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$, and  $dz=z^\prime_xdx+z^\prime_ydy$, then

$$\lim\limits_{^{\Delta z\to 0}_{n\to +\infty}} \sum_{i=1}^n\Delta z=\lim\limits_{^{\Delta z\to 0}_{n\to +\infty}} \sum_{i=1}^nz^\prime_x\Delta x +z^\prime_y\Delta y+o(\rho)=\lim\limits_{^{\Delta z\to 0}_{n\to +\infty}} \sum_{i=1}^nz^\prime_x\Delta x +z^\prime_y \Delta y$$

where I cannot tell the meaning of $\Delta z$ and $n$, but the whole formular is really similiar to the definition of *line intergral of a vertor field*, isn't it?

Additionally, I cannot find the connection between $\int dz$ and $\lim\limits_{^{\Delta z\to 0}_{n\to +\infty}} \sum_{i=1}^n\Delta z$ as well. In one variable, we just need $F(x)=\int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt$ and Newton-Leibniz formula. However, for two variables, do we need *Green's formular* instead?

Finally, I am awared that the correct formular may considered as $z(x,y)-z(x,y_0)=\int_{y_0}^y z^\prime_y(x,y)dy$ and succeed for continuous funtion $z$, but what about non-continuous funtion? Is there anything similiar to antiderivative in two variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus it is pretty clear that
$$\tag{1}
z(x,y)=z(a,y)+\int_a^x\partial_xz(u,y)\,du
$$
holds. Likewise,
$$\tag{2}
z(x,y)=z(x,b)+\int_b^y\partial_yz(x,v)\,dv\,.
$$
The differential $dz=\partial_x z\,dx+\partial_yz\,dy$ is a short form of the chain rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt}z\big(x(t),y(t)\big)=\partial_xz\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+\partial_yz\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\,.
$$
Again, by the fundamental theorem,
\begin{align}
&z\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\\
&=z\big(x(0),y(0)\big)+\int_0^t\Big\{
\partial_xz\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+\partial_yz\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\Big\}\,dt\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
You could interpret this integral as the line integral
$$\tag{4}
\int_\gamma \partial_x z\,dx+\partial_y z\,dy
$$
of the gradient vector field $\nabla z=(\partial_xz,\partial_yz)$ dotted with the tangent vectors to the curve $\gamma:[0,t]\ni s\mapsto (x(s),y(s))$.

There is no paradox when you compare (4) to (1) or (2) because it is a different integral. We cannot assume things are the same only because they look similar in certain notations.

However, when the curve $\gamma$ is parallel to the $x$-axis then $y(t)$ is constant and the integral in (3) collapses to
$$
\int_0^t\partial_xz\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\,dt\,.
$$
By a change of variables you could now easily bring this into the
form (1). Likewise, into the form (2) when the curve is parallel to the
$y$-axis.

Comment: Thanks! I should begin from the fundamental theorem of calculus, rather than learning the computations of differential, partial derivative and antiderivative. Unfortunately our country has a different teaching method, which might helpful in some situation, but really annoy me about notations.

Comment: Another question, can I think: For whatever kind of integrals in a scaler field, such as $dx,ds,dA,d\theta...$, they are equal indeed, by a specific transformation between two coordinates, or in algebraic way, a parameter. Similiar with verctor field. And the bridges of scaler field and vector fields are theorems like Greeen's function and Stokes' theorem, by dot products?

Comment: I might consider this as a question when it comes as a new post following MSE standards.

Comment: Sorry, I should read more rules of questioning... Thank you big time!